# Changing Bootstrap theme-colors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Just for the sake of easy reference, I'm creating new theme-colors as per below so I could use `bg-red` instead of `bg-danger` or `text-purple` and so on.

```
$primary        : #24305e;
$blue           : #375abb;
$indigo         : #796eff;
$purple         : #6f42c1;
$pink           : #e83e8c;
$red            : #db4446;
$orange         : #e3240C;
$yellow         : #ffc107;
$green          : #21c87a;
$teal           : #2e9cca;
$cyan           : #17a2b8;
$light          : #f6f9fc;

$theme-colors   : (
    "blue"      : $blue,
    "indigo"    : $indigo,
    "purple"    : $purple,
    "pink"      : $pink,
    "red"       : $red,
    "orange"    : $orange,
    "yellow"    : $yellow,
    "green"     : $green,
    "teal"      : $teal,
    "cyan"      : $cyan    
);

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

However, I'd like to know if this is the right way of doing it as I do notice that I'm having a duplicate `:root` variable colors. Please refer to the attached image.

[image: Bootstrap CSS-variable colors]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: try moving $theme-colors to the bottom.. write it after @import statement

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't think it is possible to do as you would lose the ability to use i.e. `bg-red` or `text-yellow`.

Comment: i think to remove or add the theme colors you need to have access to the $theme-colors variable ...

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/theming/#add-to-map

check the remove color section.

Comment: The issue isn't about adding it as what I'm doing works at least for me. It's just that, maybe it's just me, that I kinda hate to see additional CSS variables being added. Maybe the process is somewhat wrong but at the very least it works for me. Thanks for being helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That's because CSS variables are created from `$colors: ()` map, not from `$theme-colors:()` map.

You are overriding already created CSS variables by using the same name for colors.
If for, example do in

`$theme-colors:( 'vermilion':$red, )`

in `root:` you would see both `--vermilion:` and `--red:`

UPDATE: it is same as if in normal .css file you do:

```
:root {
    --red: #222222;
    --red: #333333;
}
```

`--red: #222222;` would be crossed and browser would use second `--red: #333333;`

Comment: Thank you. So I can't use the same name that overrides the default color?

Comment: you can, you're just gonna see what you are seeing right now - crossed variables. But it works normally. You didn't find any problems, right?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap defines css variables for both the `$colors` and the `$theme-colors` maps. Since the default `$colors` map includes many of the same colors that you are defining as `$theme-colors` as well, such as `blue`, `indigo`, `purple` etc. those will have the related CSS variables output twice.

The default `$colors` map is defined as (v4.5.2):

```
  (
    "blue":       $blue,
    "indigo":     $indigo,
    "purple":     $purple,
    "pink":       $pink,
    "red":        $red,
    "orange":     $orange,
    "yellow":     $yellow,
    "green":      $green,
    "teal":       $teal,
    "cyan":       $cyan,
    "white":      $white,
    "gray":       $gray-600,
    "gray-dark":  $gray-800
  )
```

It should not cause any issues as long as you are using the same color values for the same name in both `$colors` and the `$theme-colors`, or in your case as long as you are setting your `$theme-colors` map matching any of the keys in the default `$colors` map to the same variables. So in your case everything is normal and there's no need to worry at all.*

If you would like to set for example `$blue` to a different value than your `"blue"` item in `$theme-colors`, than you'd have an issue. In that case you'd need to use a different name in your `$theme-colors` map, e.g. `"blue2"` or similar.

You may find the double presence of these CSS variables annoying, but I guess it is like that so if you by accident would override one of your own colors, because of the interactions between

- the color-name variables (e.g. `$blue`),
- the default `colors()` map (which contains a `"blue": $blue` declaration and results in a `--blue` css variable added by default) and
- the `$theme-colors` map (which may be customised to also contain an item with the key `"blue":...` and would also create a `--blue` css variable).

Not filtering out these potential duplicate declarations could give you a starting point to debug the issue. Otherwise it could be much harder to figure out what is going on just by looking at the styles in your browser.

*: Note that each theme-color adds some size to your final CSS, so it's best to only include those, which are needed for sure.